# document.getElementById(" ").src not working?

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to choose the Battery 9 inside the dropdownlist.
I want the image of Battery 9 to show in the img tag.
Am I doing something wrong?

```
HEAD
function checkBatteryLife(){
if(document.getElementById('batterylifes').value == 'batterylife9'){
    document.getElementsByTagName('batteryID').src = 'battery9.png';
}
BODY
<img alt="" src="" name="batteryID" onclick="checkBatteryLife()">
</br>
<select id="batterylifes" onchange="checkBatteryLife()">
<option name="batteryIMG" value="batterylife9">Battery 9</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `batteryID` is not a valid argument to `document.getElementsByTagName()`. I would give your image tag an ID and use `document.getElementById()` on it instead. Also, unrelated: `</br>` isn't valid markup. Use `<br>` or `<br />`.

Comment: i dont know why but using <br /> gives me this error "this element is not allowed to be self closing in the schema. remove the closing slash"

Comment: Then just use `<br>`. The self-closing example is for XHTML documents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName) method will return a collection of tags by name, such as `IMG` or `SELECT`.  Passing in the `name` attribute of a tag will not yield any results.

You should probably use [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById) and pass in the `id` of the element:

```
function checkBatteryLife() {
   if(document.getElementById('batterylifes').value == 'batterylife9')
   {
      document.getElementsById('batteryID').src = 'battery9.png';
   }
}
```

..

```
<img alt="" src="" id="batteryID" onclick="checkBatteryLife()" />
<br />
<select id="batterylifes" onchange="checkBatteryLife()">
   <option name="batteryIMG" value="batterylife9">Battery 9</option>
</select>
```

You can also use [getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByName) which will return a collection of DOM elements with the specified `name` property, and then iterate through it to find the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

You need [**.getElementsByName()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByName) function instead of `.getElementByTagName()`:

```
document.getElementsByName('batteryID')[0].src = 'battery9.png';
```

As `.getElementsByName()` function returns list,and not a single element, for accessing list's element you need to use `[]` square brackets.Specifically you need first matched element with `name="batteryID"`, that's why you should use`[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it is not cross-browser compatible to get the value of the selected `option` by simply reading the value of the `select`. Instead, first detect the selected `option` then read ITS value.

```
var sel = document.getElementById('batterylifes');
if (sel.options[sel.options.selectedIndex].value == 'batterylife9') {
    //your code here...
}
```

Secondly, as many have pointed out, you are mistakenly using `getElementsByTagName` to reference a single element by its name. You need `getElementsByName()`, though this is not cross-browser compatible either. Other options:

- use jQuery or some other library
- if you don't care about old browsers, use the new `document.querySelector()` method to select the element via CSS syntax
- give the image an ID and use `getElementById()`