# how to set src attribute using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
 var news = ajaxRequest.responseText;      
 content    =  eval ("(" + news + ")");
 //var contentdataeval    =  eval ("(" + content + ")");
 console.log(content);

 for (property in content) {
       document.getElementById("1").src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+content[property].img;
       console.log (content[property].news);

 }
```

This image didn't display."document.getElementById("1").src" is  if any one can know this please help me.

Comment: Why are you passing base64 encoded image data? Why not just a path to where the image is located?

Comment: Would you be willing to use jQuery, instead? Makes life a lot easier :)

Comment: here is the link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457693/document-getelementbyid-src-not-working)

Comment: `eval` is evil. Do consider using `JSON.parse` instead. Also, incidentally, `1` is not a valid DOM ID.

Comment: @Amadan Tell me what is wrong with `eval`.

Comment: but my li id is <li id ="1">

Comment: eval function works fine.

Comment: @true: 1) It is insecure, as it can execute any valid JS (not a big issue if you control the source). 2) It slows down JS execution. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#dont-use-it), [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/json-parse-vs-eval/6). Skateboard skitching "works fine" too, until you get arrested or killed; but you still get to work quicker and safer by train.

Comment: @Amadan: It's valid in HTML5.

Comment: @Blender: Oh, look at that. Indeed, you are correct. Invalid in XML, XHTML and HTML4, but valid in HTML5.